# Hosting Web Application on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have currently deployed static content to Firebase Hosting and the site works perfectly. However, I need to deliver more 'dynamic' content such as a blog where blog posts are displayed in chronological order, etc. These can only be performed with the support of server side coding.

What options do I have if I need to host a non-static web app on Firebase?

One of the needs I have:

> Set the title & meta description of a blog post the user is viewing using server-side coding instead of JS scripting to support SEO

I know it's not related to coding directly. Just consulting the Firebase SO forum for a solution.

Comment: Firebase Hosting is for serving static content, not dynamic content. It has no built-in ability to run your code on Firebase's servers.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is it possible to use AngularJS with Firebase?

Comment: Yes. AngularJS is (for the most part) a client-side application framework. Aside from server-side components like [Angular Universal](https://scotch.io/tutorials/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2-with-angular-universal) it can be served from Firebase Hosting.

Comment: follow this tutorial step by step or watch youtube video on this blog. you will understand everything.   http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-firebase-web-hosting-and-connect.html